# promediar los resultados dinámicos de mi tabla y que de un numero entero

Tags: jquery

quiero sacar el promedio  de mi tabla de registros dinámicos y con inputs y que de un valor entero.Intente con el codigo de abajo el cual  suma automaticamente  los de class="nota" de cada registro .Funciona bien ,pero , si le pongo el codigo comentado total =parseInt(total); me dara  un resultado producto del primer cambio entre 4(por que son 4 inputs).ejemplo ingreso el numero 4 y lo divide entre 4  eso se guarda en  total pero si sigue sumando lógicamente va dar un número menor.Necesite que este sea un numero entero despues de llenar los 4 inputs.

```js
$('.nota').change(function (event) {
dataRows=$(this).parents('tr.suma');
  total = 0;
  $(dataRows).find('.nota').each(function (index, el) {
    value = $(el).val() || 0
        value =value/4;
    total += value;
    //total =parseInt(total);
         });

  $(dataRows).find('.promedio').val(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="suma">   
    <td>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="number" class="form-control nota" name="nota1[]" min="0" max="20" required>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td> 
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="number" class="form-control nota"  id="nota2" name="nota2[]" min="0" max="20" required> 
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="number" class="form-control nota" name="nota3[]" placeholder="" min="0" max="20" required>         </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="number" class="form-control nota " name="nota4[] "  placeholder=""   min="0" max="20" required>     </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="number" class="form-control promedio " placeholder=""  disabled=""  value="">
     </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Podrías agregar un ejemplo de la tabla HTML para ejemplificar mejor tu problema?

Comment: Después de editar el código y meterlo en un snippet, pese a que no debería de opinar no creo  que callarme esto te ayude. Tu código de `html` estaba completamente **mal**, la mitad de etiquetas sin cerrar, tabulaciones mal, le añades espacios y saltos de linea entre atributos de una etiqueta... Te aconsejo que revises tu código antes de exponerlo a los demás, ya sea en el trabajo, en clase o cuando se lo pases a alguien, ya que ayuda a los demás a entenderlo y en caso de StackOverflow ayuda a que la gente pueda responder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero deberías de quedarte solo con los inputs que están rellenos, y si no  están todos rellenos no hacer el cálculo:

```
var inputsRellenos = $('.nota').filter(function () {
    return this.value != "";
});
if(inputsRellenos.length == $('.nota').length){
    ...
}
```

Ademas de esto tienes que tener en cuenta que al hacer `total =parseInt(total);` `parseInt()` no redondea el valor, si no que se queda con la parte entera, por lo que `1,75` será `1`. Deberías de usar `Math.round`:

```
$(dataRows).find('.promedio').val(parseInt(Math.round(total)));
```

> La función **`Math.round()`** retorna el valor de un número redondeado al entero más cercano. 
>   Si la porción fraccionaría del número es 0.5 o mayor, el argumento es redondeado al siguiente número entero superior. Si la porción de la fracción del número es menor a 0.5, el argumento es redondeado al siguiente número entero inferior.

**[Información de Math.round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/round)**

**Snippet completo:**

```js
$('.nota').change(function (event) {
  var inputsRellenos = $('.nota').filter(function () {
    return this.value != "";
  });
  if(inputsRellenos.length == $('.nota').length){
    dataRows=$(this).parents('tr.suma');
    total = 0;
    $(dataRows).find('.nota').each(function (index, el) {
      value = $(el).val() || 0;
      value =value/4;
      total += value;
    });
    console.log("Valor decimal: "+total);
    $(dataRows).find('.promedio').val(parseInt(Math.round(total)));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="suma">   
    <td>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="number" class="form-control nota" name="nota1[]" min="0" max="20" required>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td> 
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="number" class="form-control nota"  id="nota2" name="nota2[]" min="0" max="20" required> 
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="number" class="form-control nota" name="nota3[]" placeholder="" min="0" max="20" required>         </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="number" class="form-control nota " name="nota4[] "  placeholder=""   min="0" max="20" required>     </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="number" class="form-control promedio " placeholder=""  disabled=""  value="">
     </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```